# Javascript, text area, prevent double click section

Tags: javascript, textarea, selection

I want to prevent double-click and triple click text selection in a text area.
(I want to implement my own version).

I tried to "intercept" the double click event :

```
this._wDomTextArea.addEventListener('dblclick',(event)=>{event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation()})
```

but it doesn't work. When entering my event, it's to late, the selection has already been changed.

Any suggestions ?, thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? Block the user to copy or select the text?

Comment: I want to handle the selection myself. for example for a text like  "word1:word2,  the default  behaviour will select both words , I want to select only one of the "words"
For the same reason I had to hook the Ctrl+ArrowLeft/right jeys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want to disable selection on double click, you can do this

```js
_wDomTextArea.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  if (event.detail > 1) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('double click');
  }
})
```

```html
<textarea id="_wDomTextArea"></textarea>
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works perfectly ! 
I can even detect triple clicks with it